# using <> in omron PLC

Tags: plc

I have a <>305 in my ladder logic like so

```
<> D19720 D3890
```

then after it i have a less then and a greater then like so

```
cf002  cf005
```

What it does is checks the encoders current value (d19720) with a stored value(d3890) To make sure they are the same value.  Due to it being an encoder it would not take much for the value to be + or - 2  .

Is there any way i can keep the above code but say if its greater or less then current number +/- 4 ?

thus if the stored value is 500 , then the greater then would not come on untill 504 and the less then would not come on till 496

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  What I usually do when I need an output on over an encoder range is something like

```
|                                             12.34
|--[  >=  ]---[  <=  ]--------------------------O
|  [ D100 ]   [ D100 ]
|  [ D201 ]   [ D202 ]
```

This energizes `12.34` when D100 is between the range of values in D201 and D202.  In this case you would have D100 as your encoder value, D201 would be `496` and D202 would be `504`.

Above this rung you would need, of course, a rung (always on, presumably) which would take your setpoint value (`500`) in this case, and subtract 4, then store in D201; and add 4 and store in D202.